# how to get top value of y axis on igdatachart

Tags: jquery, ajax, infragistics, ignite-ui, igdatachart

I wanna change max value of y axis labels in ignite-ui igDataChart when the maximum data of series of this axis changed. Is there any way to get the top value of y axis even the label or other things?

another thing I wanna do is change axis interval dynamically by the top value.

There is one way to get data from datasource and get the highest value but I don't want to use this way because it's a big series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [getActualMaximumValue](https://www.igniteui.com/help/api/2016.2/ui.igDataChart#methods:getActualMaximumValue) method to retrieve the actual maximum value of the axis. Notice that this works for numeric and date time axes only.

If you want to change the axis interval dinamically, you will need to write your own logic based on the max value and use the [interval](https://www.igniteui.com/help/api/2016.2/ui.igDataChart#options:axes.interval) setter